# How to identify fermion (ie. $e^-$, $\mu^-$)'s spin direction with its momentum direction?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, reference-frames, quantum-spin, scattering, helicity

Spin doesn't has classical corresponding concept. In QFT, we use Poincare group to systematically classify particles, from where we use spin. (ie. scalar, spin-$0$, fermion, spin-$\frac{1}{2}$) So how do we specify spin's direction?

I know that in QM, we can choose a preferred direction, like electron has magnetic momentum, we can use this direction. In QFT, spin appear in helicity operator, like in P&S's QFT, $$h \equiv \hat{p} \cdot \mathbf{S}=\frac{1}{2} \hat{p}_i\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\sigma^i & 0 \\
0 & \sigma^i
\end{array}\right) \tag{3.54}$$

Now, if we consider fermion's spin in a scattering process, $$e^-_R \ e^+_L \rightarrow \mu^-_R\ \mu^+_L$$
where we specify all four fermion's helicity.

I am troubled for P&S's figure 5.5 on page 147.
[image]
Before the scattering, system's spin point at $z$ direction, if the scattering process is a $s$-wave, which means spin number is a good quantum number. After the scattering, muon and anti-muon's spin also in $z$ direction, but the final states' momentum direction is random, how can we specify it's helicity in this case?

In general, the scattering is not a $s$-wave, so spin can be changed, how do we specify the spin of muon and anti-muon in this process? For example, in P&S's eq.(5.22) $$\frac{d \sigma}{d \Omega}\left(e_R^{-} e_L^{+} \rightarrow \mu_R^{-} \mu_L^{+}\right)=\frac{\alpha^2}{4 E_{\mathrm{cm}}^2}(1+\cos \theta)^2 \tag{5.22}$$
In this process, the muon's spin need to along it's direction, but why this? As in following figure in P&S's page 145.
[image]

Comment: I do not recall if P&S provide a crash course in helicity amps and rotation matrices, but that is ***exactly*** what you seem to be asking for...

Comment: Your text says it is "simplest [to choose] them to have definite helicity", as you had been using so far. So, what is the projection of the askew spin on your figure on the axis tilted by θ to its spin axis? You have learned how to do this: $d^{1/2}_{1/2,\pm1/2}$  gives you cosθ/2 and -sinθ/2  in the amps. Consult your PDG tables, 44.